# Is there a "BeforePackage" build target?

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy

I need to perform some updates on files within my project (our the output of my project) and I need to do this before the deployment package (zip file) is produced.

Is there a build target that fires between the build and packaging phases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no “BeforePackage” build target. You can use `AfterCompile` target. A little bit more hacky will be to use `GenerateDocumentation` target for your purposes, it will come before packaging if no one has overriden ordering of targets.